# How to initialize the String in kotlin

Tags: java, string, kotlin

I have a code in java where i have initialised the String like this way

```
String str = new String("");
```

but when i have converted the code to kotlin the same intilization is in the below way

```
   private val mEmailApi : String("")
```

but it is giving me a error getter and setter required can you guys please let me know the way to initialise the String in Kotlin

Thanks In Advance

Comment: val mEmailApi = ""

Comment: thanks @ramineftekhari

Comment: Was this code generated by the J2K code converter? If so, please file an issue on the kotlin bug tracker

Comment: Why would you ever write the original Java code instead of `String str = "";`?

Comment: If you are creating a string literal (e.g. you don't need create a string from an existing byte[] or char[]), do not use a constructor to create the String and instead use the literal syntax instead.  Using String literals will prevent unnecessary allocation from occurring by allowing the String to be interned (see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So `private val mEmailApi : String("")` you just define type of your field `mEmailApi`. But calling constructor during type declaration impossible.

And so: `private val mEmailApi = ""` you initialize it.

If you initialize your filed during to define, you need not to define type obviously.

Answer (score 4):

private var mString:String?=null

lateinit private var mString:String